# Issue with reading from a serial port

Tags: c++, serial-port, raspberry-pi-pico

I have connected a rasberrypi pico to my pc, and have written code in c++ to read the adc value from the pico through the serial port, however for some reason its not reading the value.

```
#include "Adc.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>

Adc::Adc(std::string port) {

    SerialPort.open(port, std::ios::in | std::ios::out);

    if (!SerialPort.is_open()) {

        std::cerr << "Error opening ADC serial port." << std::endl;

        std::exit(-1);

    }

    std::cout << "ADC port opened successfully." << std::endl;

}
Adc::~Adc() {

    SerialPort.close();

}

std::string Adc::Request() {

    // Request ADC value

    SerialPort.write("a\r", 2);


    SerialPort.flush();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

    // Read ADC value from serial port as a string
    char buffer[100];
    SerialPort.getline(buffer, 5, '\n');
    printf("ADC raw (%i): %s\n", SerialPort.gcount(), buffer);
    std::string adcValue(buffer);
 }
    return adcValue;

}
```

I have checked the python code on the pico, and it works perfectly fine so I am not sure what the problem is. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What sort of error do you see? Does your code report that it successfully opens the serial port, but outputs no data? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: @user18 I don't get an error. It just returns an empty string, and yes the serial port does open successfully. I think I may be reading the value in a wrong way?